# How can I send url of my Spreadsheet in email

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I send url of my Spreadsheet by email ?

```
My code :
var emailAddress = "my email";  
var url = "";
var subject = nom1;
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,url);
```

This code which send an email works.
But how can i get my url(speadsheet) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have your spreadsheet created, do the following steps:

- Open your spreadsheet in google drive
- Go to File->Share, a dialog should pop up with your share settings
- At the top there should be a URL that you can send to people.

Some additional Notes:

- If your spread sheet is set to private, you can change the settings such that only people who have the link are able to view the spreadsheet.

**EDIT:**
There is also getURL() in the apps script api

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getUrl()

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 Logger.log(ss.getUrl());
```

So in your case:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,ss.getUrl());
```

Comment: My code :

    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
 
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
        
     Logger.log(ss.getUrl());
     var emailAddress = "ab@gmail.com ";  
     var subject = nom1;
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,ss); 

the Error encountered: "Spreadsheet"

Comment: MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject,ss.getUrl());